# How to vertically integrate over a region with different integral bounds at every lat lon point?

Tags: python, python-xarray, metpy, era5

I am trying to calculate the vertical integral of the horizontal advection of Moist Static Energy uisng ERA5 data over a particular region. I am using xarray hence I know how to interpolate and integrate:

```
ds6 = ds5.sel(year=2000)
m = Cp*ds6.t + Lv*ds6.q + ds6.z
hadv = mpcalc.advection(m, u=ds6.u, v=ds6.v)
inter = hadv.interp(level=xs, method="cubic")
inter.integrate('level')
```

The above integrates from 1000 mb to 100 mb. I have surface pressure data for each coordinate. How do I do the integral at each coordinate only from the surface pressure to 100 mb instead?

Here is what I have tried:

```
Ps = ds10.sp.sel(time='2021-12-01')
selected = inter.where(inter.level < Ps) #selecting data points above Ps only
selected.dropna(dim='level') #removing Nan so that we can integrate
```

This does not work because it removes all data points below the maximum Ps of any data point, and spatial variability because of Ps is gone. What do I do?

Comment: hi, doesn't answer your question but I think ERA5 has vertical integrals of energy fluxes and moisture fluxes in case that helps (see under section "vertical integrals")

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The available vertical integrals do not have what I want unfortunately, they only provide vertical integrals of basic quantities. I wish to calculate the vertical integral of MSE,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have the following dataset `ds`:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lon: 10, lat: 20, level: 50)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  * lat      (lat) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
  * level    (level) float64 1.1e+03 1.078e+03 1.056e+03 ... 54.49 32.24 10.0
Data variables:
    sfc_p    (lon, lat) int64 1031 980 1047 1028 988 ... 990 978 1026 1055 1003
    adv      (lon, lat, level) float64 -0.9586 -0.04061 1.627 ... -1.318 0.8371
```

Then you can apply a function to every individual vertical profile using `groupby`. Check this out:

```
all_dims_except_level = [d for d in ds.dims if (d != "level")]
adv_gridpoint = ds.stack(gridpoint=all_dims_except_level)


def integral_from_sfc_p_to_p(data, target_pressure):
    sfc_p_at_gridpoint = data.sfc_p.values.item()

    levels_between_sfc_p_and_upper_limit = data.level.where(
        (data.level > target_pressure) & (data.level < data.sfc_p), drop=True
    ).values

    target_levels = np.concatenate(
        [[sfc_p_at_gridpoint], levels_between_sfc_p_and_upper_limit, [target_pressure]]
    )

    data_interp_to_sfc_p = data.interp(level=target_levels)
    data_integrated = data_interp_to_sfc_p.integrate("level")
    return data_integrated


print(
    adv_gridpoint.groupby("gridpoint")
    .apply(integral_from_sfc_p_to_p, target_pressure=100)
    .unstack()
)
```

yields:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lon: 10, lat: 20)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  * lat      (lat) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
Data variables:
    sfc_p    (lon, lat) int64 1031 980 1047 1028 988 ... 990 978 1026 1055 1003
    adv      (lon, lat) float64 -172.2 61.96 -109.3 22.05 ... -23.87 182.0 235.1
```